# How to track a C struct member in the XCode debugger to see when it becomes NaN?

Tags: c, xcode, macos, struct

One of the members in a struct is NaN. It was declared as a float and initialised at 0.0f. I'm trying to debug this in Xcode by stepping through the code and checking when the value changes into NaN.

My question: how do I keep the value of the struct member in view? I can type `print struct.member` in the debug window every time I step into a line of code, but I'm hoping there is a better way where the value remains conveniently displayed in a window while stepping. **>** Update In Visual Studio I could define a window and drag variables to be monitored in there, they remained visible while stepping through the code, this was very helpful. Does Xcode have a similar feature?

My other question: how does one instruct `lldb` to assign a value to a struct member? **>** Update This one is answered.

Comment: `struct_value.member = new_value;` if you have a structure; `struct_ptr->member = new_value;` if you have a pointer.  Use `strcpy()` or whatever else is relevant if you need to.

Comment: When I type that into the debugger field I get `(lldb) EnginesLocal_.RootT25STempRatio = 1
error: 'EnginesLocal_' is not a valid command.
error: Unrecognized command 'EnginesLocal_.RootT25STempRatio'. `. Doesn't it require some `set` command?

Comment: So you're using `lldb` and not `gdb`?  I'm not that keen on `lldb` and don't yet fully understand it.  Have you tried `help` and/or `?`?  That should get you started down the line.  I'd have to run it to get any further.

Comment: Yes, apologies. Will edit question.

Comment: Using Help helped: answer to second question is `po EnginesLocal_.RootT25STempRatio = 1`